# Find index of n number of small elements next to each others in array

Tags: c++

I am stuck in a simple problem. I need to find index of n numbers of  smallest elements next to each others in an array. So if my array is [-1,-3,4,2,-5,-6] and n=3 my answer would be 5,4 and 1(because first 3 smallest elements are -6(index 5),-5(index 4) and -3(index 1)). What would be the best way to do it in C++ without any library function ? This is what i came up with :

```
int getPos(int* arr,int n,int y)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
         if(arr[i]==y)
            return i;
    }
}  


int* sorted=new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    sorted[i]=diff[i];
}
sort(sorted,sorted+n);
for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
{
    int y=sorted[i];
    int k=getPos(diff,n,y);
}
```

Here diff is the unsorted array and sorted is the sorted array. This function works fine when there is no repeated element. But if my diff array is [-1,-1,2,-2,-2] and sorted array is [-2,-2,-1,-1,2] So in 1st iteration it grabs index for -2. Now in 2nd iteration it will again grab index of index of -2(1st -2 in my array not the 2nd) . So how to make my code work for repeating elements ?

Comment: What does `consecutive` mean in your case ?

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to help you doing your homeworks. We won't help you if you haven't tried anything on your own. Please, consider doing some researches by yourself and show us what you tried.

Comment: Means a sorted sequence. Like in my example first smallest element is -6,2nd smallest is -5 and 3rd smallest is -3. I want to extract the index of these elements. So i am considering -6,-5 and -3 as consecutive.

Comment: That is not what consecutive means at all. It is supposed to mean something like `next to each others`

Comment: Well. I am seeking help because i am stuck as i told. I tried to solve the in linear searching way. So i grab the first smallest element finds its index. Then i am lost because for the second iteration it should find again the smallest element if i wont use some condition. It should use 2 loop but again as i told you i am stuck !

Comment: I know the answer is something like "Selection sort" procedure but should i use some boolean array so that i can mark which element is visited or not . Or is there a simpler solution ?

Comment: Being *stuck* doesn't mean anything here. Show us what you tried, what you got and what you expected so we can start thinking **together** about the issue.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited it. I dont want solution. An idea will be helpful here.

Comment: You should edit your post with a sorted list.  Otherwise, -5 is not consecutive to -3, *as far as position in the array* goes.

Comment: @NazmusSalehin just a suggestion: allocate a memory at runtime for n variable for 2 arrays (one for sorted value and second for its index) and each time while traversing original buffer, sort the above array and reposition the index.
I guess, it should solve your problem

Comment: *"in C++ without any library function"* - In other words: Using C++, just without C++. This is not a practical programming problem. Voting to close.

Comment: Well i mean without using stl like algorithms. Again i dont want code for the problem. Just give me an idea about doing these . You can negative vote if you don't want  to give idea . Thanks

Comment: @NazmusSalehin if you need another solution than what I gave, please say. I will be glad to help

Comment: @Ninetainedo i have given what i came up with but my solution not working for repeated elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break down your task to smaller tasks and them achieve each small task in c++. You basically want:

1. To find the smallest item of an array `n` times.
2. For each min item, get it's index as well.
3. Output the found indexs to screen.

That's not very complicated. Do some research about the basics such as **loops** (to do something n times), **functions** (to do the same code of finding the smallest item in an array - with functions you write it once and call it again when you want to use that code) - you can also use known `sort`ing functions, **arrays** in `c++` and **output** to screen.

First try writing your own code before asking for it here :)

Comment: Please see what i came up with in the post. I have edited this

Comment: @NazmusSalehin You did it good. To solve tour problem now - save the last found value in a variable, and compare it to the new minimum found. If they are equal, don't output the current's index. (Or yes, I dont think it matters).

Comment: If the answer helped you, consider upvoting or accepting it.

Comment: Thank you. Highly appreciated :)

Comment: Well my problem is a part of codeforces problem. Here i need all the indexes of any n  numbers of repeating or non repeating smallest element. So if i don't output if value are equal what should be the approach here to print all the corresponding indexes ?

Comment: @NazmusSalehin You can save the indexes to another array. Or, you can iterate the array once - find the min. Than again, and print all of it's indexes. Then, so you wont find the same min again, save the last min in a variable and next time print only if it is higher than the last min (which is the next min in order).